# How to find the maximum and minimum values of $\left|\sin 2x\right|+\left|\cos 2x\right|$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

The expression is :$$\left|\sin2x\right|+\left|\cos2x\right|$$

For the maximum value I can ignore the absolute value and can get $$\sqrt2$$

But finding the minimum is what stumps me

I can understand it is $1$ by guessing but is there a rigorous approach ?

I didn't try differentiation because it can not be used on absolute value function .

Thank you in advance .

Comment: $(|\sin 2x|+|\cos 2x|)^2=(\sin 2x)^2 + (\cos 2x)^2 + 2|\sin 2x||\cos 2x|=1+2|\sin 2x||\cos 2x|\ge 1$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner how are we not getting a wrong answer by squaring? I have learnt that squaring gives wrong results.

Comment: squaring could sometimes introduce extraneous results, but in this case the expression must be non-negative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1** $2x=t$ we have $${(|\sin t|+|\cos t|)}^2=1+|\sin 2t|\ge 1$$

The conclusion is now obvious

**Method 2** as $0\le |\sin t|,|\cos t|\le 1$ we must have $$|\sin t|+|\cos t|\ge |\sin^2 t|+|\cos^2 t|=\sin^2 t+\cos ^2t=1$$

Comment: I have always hated squaring ,it makes us loose solution or gains them .why did nothing go wrong here ?

Comment: I always wonder why, if something is obvious, that it needs to be pointed out?

Comment: @Glowingbluejuicebox another method is put

Comment: In the first method how can we square it ? Do we lose or gain anything??

Comment: @Glowingbluejuicebox i started out with a known inequality ,it we take square roots  we only have to take pesitive value as sum of modulus is always  greater than or equal to zero